# Translation of words in spotlight

Tags: software-recommendation, spotlight, software, dictionary, language

I am looking for an extension for spotlight on Yosemite, which allows an offline translation of english words into german and vice-versa. Similar to the inbuilt dictionary, but rather giving a translation of the word instead of a definition.
It should also be lightweight, so not slowing the system or spotlight down.
Is there such a software?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be quite what you're looking for, but have a look at [Flashlight](http://flashlight.nateparrott.com/). It allows you to use plugins for Spotlight, including translation plugins. I don't think the translation ones are offline, but it's open source, so maybe you could figure out a way to download an offline translation dictionary and modify an existing plugin to use this offline dictionary?